Pause all the audios and then resume only the ones that where playing
I'm trying to make an application in which there are several ambient sound audios. One functionality I want to add is that, when I click on a checkbox, all the audios that are playing will stop, and when I uncheck the checkbox only the audios that were playing before I checked it will resume.
I'm using React and Redux. This is what I have.
import "./styles.css";
import { useRef, useReducer } from "react";

const audioActionType = {
  TOGGLE_PLAY: "TOGGLE_PLAY",
  SET_VOLUME: "SET_VOLUME",
  TOGGLE_ALL_PAUSED: "TOGGLE_ALL_PAUSED",
};

const initialAudioState = {
  audios: [
    {
      playing: false,
      id: 1,
      volume: 25,
      title: "Coffe making",
      src: "..//audio/espresso-machine.mp3",
    },
    {
      playing: false,
      id: 2,
      volume: 25,
      title: "Coffe machine",
      src: "..//audio/espresso-machine.mp3",
    },
  ],
  allPaused: false,
};

function AudioReducer(stateAudios, actionAudios) {
  switch (actionAudios.type) {
    case audioActionType.TOGGLE_PLAY:
      return {
        ...stateAudios,
        audios: stateAudios.audios.map((audio) =>
          audio.id === actionAudios.id
            ? { ...audio, playing: !audio.playing }
            : audio
        ),
      };
    case audioActionType.SET_VOLUME:
      return {
        ...stateAudios,
        audios: stateAudios.audios.map((audio) =>
          audio.id === actionAudios.id
            ? { ...audio, volume: actionAudios.volume }
            : audio
        ),
      };
    case audioActionType.TOGGLE_ALL_PAUSED:
      const anyAudioPlaying = { ...stateAudios.audios };
      console.log(anyAudioPlaying);
      if (stateAudios.allPaused) {
        return {
          ...stateAudios,
          audios: stateAudios.audios.map((audio) => ({
            ...audio,
            playing: false,
          })),
          allPaused: false,
        };
    default:
      return stateAudios;
  }
}

export default function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AudioReducer, initialAudioState);

  const audioRefs = useRef(
    //creaamos una referencia para los audios para poder pausarlos, cambiar el volumen, etc
    state.audios.reduce((acc, audio) => {
      //con reduce recorremos el array de audios y creamos un objeto que almacena todos los aduios con el acc (contador) como el id del audio y su valor como el src del audio. quedaria algo así: {1: src1.mp3, 2:src2.mp3}
      acc[audio.id] = new Audio(audio.src);
      return acc;
    }, {})
  ).current; //el current lo ponemos aquí para no tener que usarlo cada vez que queramos acceder al valor del Ref

  const togglePlay = (id) => {
    dispatch({ type: "TOGGLE_PLAY", id });
    const audio = audioRefs[id];
    state.audios.find((audio) => audio.id === id).playing
      ? audio.pause()
      : audio.play();
  };

  const setVolume = (id, volume) => {
    dispatch({ type: "SET_VOLUME", id, volume });
    audioRefs[id].volume = volume / 100;
  };

  console.log(state);

  return (
    <div id="sounds-section" className="sections">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id="pause"
        name="pause"
        checked={state.allPaused}
        onChange={() => dispatch({ type: "TOGGLE_ALL_PAUSED" })}
      />
      <label htmlFor="pause"> Pause all</label>
      <div id="sounds">
        {state.audios.map((audio) => (
          <div className="sound" key={audio.id}>
            <div>
              <button
                onClick={() => togglePlay(audio.id)} //es importante poner el () porque sinó estamos llamando a la función cuando se crea el objeto y no cuando clicamos en el botón
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                  __html: audio.playing ? "&#x23F8;" : "&#x25B6;",
                }}
              />
              <h4>{audio.title}</h4>
            </div>
            {audio.playing && (
              <input
                className="volume"
                type="range"
                min="0"
                max="100"
                step="1"
                value={audio.volume}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setVolume(audio.id, e.target.value);
                }}
              />
            )}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


I'm having trouble with how to review the previous state before the allPaused converts all the playing atributes to false.

Also just FYI, the useReducer hook is unrelated to Redux other than implementing a similar pattern of actions/reducer functions.

Maybe in the audioActionType.TOGGLE_ALL_PAUSED reducer case you toggle only the allPaused state and handle the playback in the UI like you are, but modified to take the allPaused state into account. When the allPaused state is again toggled, you'll still have whatever existing state for what is playing back since it was never updated.
AudioReducer
function AudioReducer(stateAudios, actionAudios) {
  switch (actionAudios.type) {
    case audioActionType.TOGGLE_PLAY:
      return {
        ...stateAudios,
        audios: stateAudios.audios.map((audio) =>
          audio.id === actionAudios.id
            ? { ...audio, playing: !audio.playing }
            : audio
        ),
      };

    case audioActionType.SET_VOLUME:
      return {
        ...stateAudios,
        audios: stateAudios.audios.map((audio) =>
          audio.id === actionAudios.id
            ? { ...audio, volume: actionAudios.volume }
            : audio
        ),
      };

    case audioActionType.TOGGLE_ALL_PAUSED:
      return {
        ...stateAudios,
        allPaused: !stateAudios.allPaused,
      };

    default:
      return stateAudios;
  }
}

App
export default function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AudioReducer, initialAudioState);

  const audioRefs = useRef(
    state.audios.reduce((acc, audio) => {
      acc[audio.id] = new Audio(audio.src);
      return acc;
    }, {})
  ).current;

  const togglePlay = (id) => {
    dispatch({ type: "TOGGLE_PLAY", id });
    const audio = audioRefs[id];
    state.audios.find((audio) => audio.id === id).playing
      ? audio.pause()
      : audio.play();
  };

  const setVolume = (id, volume) => {
    dispatch({ type: "SET_VOLUME", id, volume });
    audioRefs[id].volume = volume / 100;
  };

  const toggleAllPaused = () => {
    dispatch({ type: "TOGGLE_ALL_PAUSED" });

    state.audios.forEach(audio => {
      // If all audios are currently paused
      if (state.allPaused) {
        // And the current audio was previously playing, play audio
        if (audio.playing) {
          audio.play();
        }
      // Else just pause all the adios
      } else {
        audio.pause();
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <div id="sounds-section" className="sections">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id="pause"
        name="pause"
        checked={state.allPaused}
        onChange={toggleAllPaused}
      />
      <label htmlFor="pause"> Pause all</label>
      <div id="sounds">
        {state.audios.map((audio) => (
          <div className="sound" key={audio.id}>
            <div>
              <button
                onClick={() => togglePlay(audio.id)}
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                  __html: audio.playing ? "&#x23F8;" : "&#x25B6;",
                }}
              />
              <h4>{audio.title}</h4>
            </div>
            {audio.playing && (
              <input
                className="volume"
                type="range"
                min="0"
                max="100"
                step="1"
                value={audio.volume}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setVolume(audio.id, e.target.value);
                }}
              />
            )}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


Thank you very much! Also, for the "play" and "pause" icon to sync, should I put the audioRefs[audio.id].pause() in the if of the button?

@amiindless You could also use state.allPaused in the condition, something like __html: !audio.playing || state.allPaused ? "&#x25B6;" : "&#x23F8;" (note that I  inverted the boolean expression). Then it's up to you to determine what the logic should be if all are paused and only 1 audio element is unpaused.
